# Why is $H_1 \le G \land H_2 \le G$ necessary in $a(H_1 \cap H_2) = aH_1 \cap aH_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

The problem is as follows:

> $G$ is a group and $H_1$ and $H_2$ are its two subgroups (i.e., $H_1 \le G \land H_2 \le G$). To prove that $a(H_1 \cap H_2) = aH_1 \cap aH_2$.

Here is my trial:

On the one hand, for $a(H_1 \cap H_2) \subseteq aH_1 \cap aH_2$:
$b \in a(H_1 \cap H_2) \implies \exists h \in H_1 \cap H_2: b = ah \implies b \in aH_1 (h \in H_1) \land b \in aH_2 (h \in H_2) \implies b \in aH_1 \cap aH_2.$
On the other hand, for $aH_1 \cap aH_2 \subseteq a(H_1 \cap H_2)$:
$b \in aH_1 \cap aH_2 \implies b \in aH_1 \land b \in aH_2 \implies \exists h_1 \in H_1, h_2 \in H_2: b = ah_1 \land b = ah_2 \implies h_1 = h_2 \implies \exists h (= h_1 = h_2) \in H_1 \cap H_2: b = ah \implies b \in a(H_1 \cap H_2).$

In this argument, I do not (in my opinion) use the assumption of $H_1 \le G \land H_2 \le G$. Therefore,

> What is wrong with my argument?
>   Why is $H_1 \le G \land H_2 \le G$ necessary in $a(H_1 \cap H_2) = aH_1 \cap aH_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need for the $H_1 \le G \land H_2 \le G$ condition hinges on the definition used for expressions of the form $aH$.  In all cases, $aH$ is defined as

$$aH := \{ah\;|\;h \in H\}$$

but some textbooks may limit this definition only to those $H$ that are also subgroups.  I imagine this is the case whenever expressions like $aH$ are used as shorthand for "left coset", which would make sense only if $H$ is a subgroup.

In fact, a proof having the same structure as yours shows that, for any *injective* function $f$, and any *subsets* $A$ and $B$ of $\mathrm{dom}(f)$,

$$f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B).$$

(Actually, $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$ holds for *any* function $f$, but the reverse inclusion holds only if $f$ is injective.)

Now, for any $a \in G$, define $f_a: x \mapsto ax$, and your statement follows as a corollary of the equality above.  (Every such $f_a$ is injective, and in fact bijective, since $f_a^{-1} = f_{a^{-1}}$.  BTW, this injectivity condition makes its appearance in your proof in the step $b = ah_1 \land b = ah_2 \implies h_1 = h_2$.)

Comment: I will check the textbook tomorrow for the definition of $aH$. Thanks for the generalization.

Comment: I have checked the textbook and it does not limit the definition of $aH$ only to those $H$ that are also subgroups. However, I agree with you.